# sqlite without primary key?

Tags: android, sqlite

Is there a way in Android to have an sqlite database which does have one or two tables which do NOT have a primary key?

The reason being that the column with the primary key is to be implemented later in the process, I do not know what that is supposed to be yet but I want to get the database working.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You don't need to define a primary key. By default, the table will have a key based on the `rowid` value.

More information can be found in the documentation [here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid).